# excel formula sumif formula not calculating

Tags: excel-formula

I have used the sumif formula for many years but I find it is not working now. The report I have was first a text or pdf that was converted into an excel file. I have done the F9 key that did not work. I have checked the compatibility mode setting. The cells are number fields not text or general. I could use some expert advise how to make the formulas work.

Here is a screen shot of a sample page. The formula is in cell J6 thru J8, the formula in in the formula bar.

[image: screen shot of sample problem]

Comment: Because this was converted, my bet is that there is white space around one of your values that you are testing (like spaces or tabs after the numbers/text). Because `"  This      "` doesn't equal `"This"` your sumif is failing. You can use formula `=Trim()` to clean up the white space on your data.

Comment: I gave it a try and it did not work. I also inserted a column next to B and C and enter =trim(D4) then dragged the formulas down the column. I modified the formula to pull from the new column still not working. :(

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,I6,B:B,$J$5)
```

If this still gives you troubles go with:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"*"&I6&"*",B:B,"*"&$J$5&"*")
```

And to put it into perspective of your formula:

```
{=SUM(IF((A:A="*"&I6&"*")*(B:B="*"&$J$5&"*"),C:C))}
```